# CKEditor with angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

I have array of html elements each element mush user change it with `CKEditor`. After user change elements and I loop in array, I get the old value.

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in site">
        <textarea ng-model="item" ckeditor="ckeditorOptions"></textarea>
        <input type="button" value="Test unit" ng-click="elementUnit(item)" />
 </div>
```

In controller

```
$scope.ckeditorOptions = {
        language: 'en',
        allowedContent: true,
        entities: true
}; 

$scope.uploadContent = function(site) {
        console.log(site);
        for (var i = 0; i < site.length; i++) {
            console.log(site[i]); // Get old value !!
        }
}

$scope.elementUnit= function(item) {
        console.log(item);// in this case I get new value
}
```

What can I do for this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is thee code?

Comment: I have added code @Sajeetharan

Comment: you might have to post the items array too

Comment: when I post array, it return with old values

Comment: You have shown us only half of your code , difficult to help